# Intersection of Cartesian product and set - what is the meaning?

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

I came across the following two definitions in a book about Integer Programming:

> **Definition 1.1** A subset of $R^n$ described by a finite set of linear constraints $P=\{x \in R^n: Ax \leq b \}$ is a polyhedron.
>
> **Definition 1.2** A polyhedron $P \subseteq R^{n+p}$ is a *formulation* for a set $X \subseteq Z^n \times R^p$ if and only if $X=P \cap (Z^n \times R^p)$.

I don't really understand definition 1.2. Could anyone explain to me in simple language what this tries to say? I especially don't get this: '$X=P \cap (Z^n \times R^p)$'; what does it mean to take the intersection of a set and a Cartesian product (I know what a Cartesian product is but how can that intersect with a regular set)?

Comment: Note that in Defn. 1.2 you have $P \subset \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^p$.

Comment: $Z^n \times R^p = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_n, x_{n+1}, \ldots, x_{n+p}) \in R^{n+p} \colon x_1, \ldots, x_n \in Z\}$.

Comment: @copper.hat Ah, I didn't realize that. Then how can it be that in the definition above (1) $P$ is defined as a subset of $R^n$? Is $P \subseteq R^{n+p} $ just because $R^n \subset R^{n+p}$ and $P\subseteq R^n$?

Comment: $n$ is arbitrary, a placeholder. The $n$ in the first definition and the second definition are different.

Comment: @copper.hat Ah ok, that makes sense now. Still I find definition 2 confusing though. Would it be possible for you to clarify that in somewhat 'lower mathematical language'? I hardly encountered Cartesian products before which makes it hard...

Comment: @njguliyev's comment above might help?

Comment: @copper.hat Not really. I understood already what it means to be an element of $Z^n \times R^p$. However, what I find confusing is how this is equivalent to $X=P \cap (Z^n \times R^p)$. Could you maybe elaborate on why that is the case?

Comment: Think of the case $p=0$ and $n=2$. Then $X \subset \mathbb{Z}^2$ consists of a few lattice points in the plane. Even more specifically, take $X=\{(0,0),(1,0),(1,0),(1,1)\}$. Now write down a system of inequalities which bounds a region $P \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ so that $P \cap \mathbb{Z}^2 = X$, that is, $P$ *only* contains the points of the lattice in the set $X$. (There are infinitely many different systems of inequalities you could write down, hence many *formulations*.)

Comment: @dls That makes a lot of sense! If you make that into an answer I'll give you full points! Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is a definition. It says that $P$ is a formulation for the set $X$ **iff** it can be written in that form. For example, the set $P= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | -1 \le x \le 1,\, -1 \le y \le 1 \} $ is a formulation for the set $X=\{-1,0,1\} \times [-1,1]$ because $X=P \cap (\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R})$. Note that the set $P'=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | -1.5 \le x \le 1.5,\, -1 \le y \le 1 \} $ is also a formulation for the set $X$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks a lot! That really helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When unpacking definitions, it often helps to think of a very simple example. Let's take the case $p=0$ and $n=2$. Think of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ as the lattice points embedded in the Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now take $X \subset \mathbb{Z}^2$ be a very specific set, say the corners of a square, $X=\{(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1)\}$.

Now graph the region $P$ satisfying the inequalities
$$
0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
0 \leq y \leq 1.
$$
Then $P$ is a square in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $X = P \cap \mathbb{Z}^2$. So the region $P$ contains precisely the lattice points in the set $X$. We call $P$ or the system of inequalities a *formulation* for the set $X$. But there are many formulations, for instance the region $P'$ given by
$$
0 \leq x \leq 1.1 \\
0 \leq y \leq 1.9.
$$
Now come up with examples where $p>0$.